# How to walk-jump like a pro in condition zero

Tags: counter-strike

While playing online [I am a newbie to CS-CZ online gaming], i noticed some players walking and jumping simultaneously , without decreasing their walking speed.

I am amused , is there a key combination for that , or an extra installable mod .

Also , is it considerable for hacking.

P.S.- I am not talking about 'bunny hopping'.

Comment: Just a wild guess but maybe it was a [doubleduck](http://xtreme-jumps.eu/page.php?59)?

Comment: If not, you might just be talking about crouchhopping. Just tap and release crouch very quickly as you're running, and you'll jump slightly.

Comment: Thank you for your replies . I was somehow expecting a detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure your controls as follows:

- in CS:CZ option menu, go to controls tab.
- go to 'duck/crouch' action and choose the "secondary" field.
- after selecting "secondary button" move your mouse scroller in any direction which you feel is comfortable.
- set mouse scroll up/down for 'duck' as the secondary option, primary being <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (default)

So when you move forward and use mouse scroll simultaneously , you would see that your player is "walking-jumping".

It is not a hack.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about the bunny hop.  You just jump while crouching and move your mouse forward.  On the screen you see yourself looking forward and jumping.